# How do I access programmatically created refs in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I would like to access refs in a vue.js component, where the ref itself is created dynamically like so:

```
<style>
</style>
<template>
  <div>
    <lmap class="map" v-for="m in [1, 2, 3]" :ref="'map' + m"></lmap>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
module.exports = {
    components: {
        lmap: httpVueLoader('components/base/map.vue'),
    },
    mounted: function(){
        console.log('all refs', this.$refs);
        // prints an object with 3 keys: map1, map2, map3

        console.log('all ref keys', Object.keys(this.$refs));
        // would expect ["map1", "map2", "map3"], prints an empty array instead
        Vue.nextTick().then(() => {
            console.log('map1', this.$refs["map1"]);
            // would expect a DOM element, instead prints undefined
        })
    },
    destroyed: function(){

    },
    methods: {

    },
}
</script>
```

However this seems not to work (see above in the comments), and I can't figure why.

Comment: This should work fine. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are **importing the component asynchronously**, with **httpVueLoader**, which then downloads and imports the component only when the component is rendered from the dom, therefore, the component has not yet been imported into the nextTick callback.

I suggest you put a **loaded event** in the map.vue component, maybe in mounted lifecycle , which will be listened to in the father, example `@loaded = "showRefs"`

surely when the **showRefs(){ }** method is invoked, you will have your refs populated ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until components have been rendered / updated. This works:

```
module.exports = {
    data: function () {
        return {
        };
    },
    components: {
        lmap: httpVueLoader('components/base/map.vue'),
    },
    mounted: function(){
    },
    destroyed: function(){
    },
    updated: function(){
        Vue.nextTick().then(() => {
            console.log('all ref keys', Object.keys(this.$refs));
            console.log('map1', this.$refs['map1'][0].$el);
        })
    },
    methods: {
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a template string e.g

```
`map${m}`
```